# Which kind of distributions can decision trees learn (well)?

Tags: distributions, classification, cart

Suppose I have a classification task in $\mathbb{R}^d$, given by a distribution $P$ and training data $D$. The decision boundary is
$$B = \{x \; : \; P(Y=1|x) = P(Y=0|x)\}$$
Assume I am learning a decision tree (not a random forest) of a given depth $k$, trying to classify the data correctly in each leaf. The loss function is the distance to the decision boundary.
Of course, it depends on the geometry of $B$ on how well this task can be performed. If $B$ can be approximated by axis-aligned cuts, we can almost perfectly learn $B$ using the tree.

My question: Is there research on distributional (not so much geometric) assumptions on $P$ that give bounds on how good the optimal tree is?

Answer (score 0):

One of the great advantages of decision trees is their relative robustness against different distributions. Because they simply make axis-parallel cuts in the data, their performance is generally considered invariant to skewness. In other words, one of the big advantages of decision trees is that they are aggressively non-parametric. I can't find any empirical research directly addressing this, but researchers commonly allude to it in there research. See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4466856/) and [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1007730.1007738?casa_token=O5x6tqb5RUAAAAAA%3ArQkfkkmitvg-sPIGq7kZGvUwHOVFIueXd18m46qmFqj0YazRKSV9XmRRzDEIePpGw6bW7f6YKZb3).

The biggest limitation seems to be a tendency to struggle with class imbalance, as I found [a couple](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10618-011-0222-1.pdf) of [different research papers](https://www.eecs.uottawa.ca/%7Enat/Workshop2003/chawla.pdf) that address this. I would note that if possible you should consider random forests as they are substantially better.